# Class contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods

Tags: php, fatal-error

> Fatal error: Class Validate contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (BaseValidator::SetRange) in C:\wamp\www\jump\task3\day8\abstract.php on line 21

```
<?php
    abstract class BaseValidator
    {
        abstract function Validate($string);
        abstract function SetRange($string);
    }
    class Validate extends BaseValidator
    {
        public function Validate($string)
        {
            if (!preg_match('/[^A-Za-z]/', $string))
            {
                echo "'{$string}' contains only alphabets!";
            } 
            if (is_numeric($string))
            {
                echo "'{$string}' Conatins No. Only!<br/>";
                echo '<br>';
            }
        }
    }
    class setRange extends BaseValidator
    {
        public function SetRange($string)
        {
            if(!(strlen($string)>4 && strlen($string)<10))
            {
                echo "You are not in range of 4-10";
            }
        }
    }
    $obj = new Validate();
    $obj = $obj->Validate("Hello");
    $obj = new SetRange("hello");
    $obj = $obj->SetRange("hello");
?>
```

Comment: I am new to phpand I can't understand how to use the second function SetRange($string)

Comment: must be defined at least empty Validate::SetRange http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php

Comment: error messages are sometimes not worded clearly, no need to be rude about it..

Answer (score 23):

Dumbing down the error message for you:

> Fatal error: Class Validate contains 1 abstract method and must
>   therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods
>   (BaseValidator::SetRange) in C:\wamp\www\jump\task3\day8\abstract.php
>   on line 21

#### Breakdown

1. Your class `Validate` only contains **`1`** abstract method.
2. The class that `Validate` extends which is `BaseValidator` has **`2`** abstract methods set.
3. **That means your original class (`Validate`) requires the second abstract method to be specified within it (in this case that would be `setRange()`) to be set.**

That means you could simply set the function in your class but have it empty:

```
class Validate extends BaseValidator
    {
        public function Validate($string)
        {
            if (!preg_match('/[^A-Za-z]/', $string))
            {
                echo "'{$string}' contains only alphabets!";
            } 
            if (is_numeric($string))
            {
                echo "'{$string}' Conatins No. Only!<br/>";
                echo '<br>';
            }
        }

        public function setRange($string) {}
    }
```

---

**SIDE NOTE:**

You will require the same as above for your `setRange` class as it is extended your `BaseValidator` class.

```
class setRange extends BaseValidator
    {
        public function Validate($string){}

        public function SetRange($string)
        {
            if(!(strlen($string)>4 && strlen($string)<10))
            {
                echo "You are not in range of 4-10";
            }
        }
    }
```

[### Example](https://eval.in/154654)

Comment: Thanks bro I got your idea and thank you so much @darren please help me how to call the setRange($string) function

Comment: @user3656133 what exactly do you need `setRange()` to do? its rather simple : `$obj->setRange('range to set or something?')`?

Comment: I've seen answers explaining how to add the methods, and I've seen answers explaining how to make the class abstract (the other option proposed in the error message), but I haven't seen answers explaining how I should decide between the two solutions... something to help me understand the implications better - I have to touch code I didn't write.